# What is the best way to detect CPU cache misses when running an algorithm?

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-cache

We have an algorithm which is performing poorly and we believe it's because of CPU cache misses. Nevertheless, we can't prove it because we don't have any way of detecting them. Is there any way to tell how many CPU cache misses an algorithm produces? We can port it to any language which could allow us to detect them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to find out such kind of issues is to use profilers and collect cache related performance counters.

I would recommend to check following tools:

- Intel® VTune™ Amplifier XE (supports: linux and windows; C/C++, Java, .NET) - http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/
- OProfile - http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/

Is it possible to see the overall structure of your algorithm (if it is not too long)?

Answer (score 0):

Intel CPUs keep performance counters that you can extract with some assembler instructions.

Could you (1) baseline cache misses on a quiescent system, (2) run the program and compare?

See Volume 3B of the [Intel Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) Section 18 Page 15 (18-15) for the assembler you would have to write up.